# Create Debain image to restore later

Tags: debian, web-hosting

I have remote hosted server with debian os.

I need to some way create image of this so that I can restore it later if needed.

suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for so-called "virtualization" software, perhaps especially "OS virtualization".

- [OS level virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system%E2%80%93level_virtualization)

  - Among the listed software, [Docker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) (a wrapper of LXC) seems to be quickly getting popular.

The host OS (the existing Debian in your case) is only for managing guest OS installations.  You will mostly work on the guest OSes when you setup services such as MySQL or Wordpress and configure routing to particular guest OS on the host OS.  You can take as many snapshots of the guest OSes as you need and can rewind to a specific snapshots at any times.

Note that the guest OS kernel must not be different from the host kernel if you choose OS virtualization software.  If you wanna avoid such a restriction, you need to select "full" (aka "hardware") virtualization software.  I like VirtualBox for this.

- [Full virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_virtualization)
- [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)

  - [Vagrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29), a wrapper of VirtualBox, seems to be quickly getting popular.